# SharePoint web services web site error Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: web-services, administration, central-administration, iis

I am working on SharePoint 2013 , and inside the IIS i have noted a question mark icon beside the "SharePoint Web Services" website, and when i browse the http & https , from IIS->select the Sharepint Web Services -->browse , i got the following error :-

```
Service Unavailable


HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

so can anyone advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site is not accessible and can only be accessed through the applications within this
 website. For verifying the same, expand the website and click on topology and try to access the service.svc through browser. It will work - try

```
http://localhost:32843/Topology/topology.svc)
```

Also, don't worry about the ? mark next to the WebSite icon. It usually means you have multiple bindings or multiple services  installed on the website.

Comment: but i think there is a problem since if i try to open the metadata service i will get the following error :- he Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been started. Please Contact your Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont try to browse the root only go to the .svc file and click on browse and you wouldnt see the issue.
Like http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc would browse fine but http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication would throw error